# React's Promise: How to convert array into json

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native

I have a list of pages obtained from an API that I stored in an array. I want to convert the array into JSON data so I can access the objects and store them in a state variable.

I've tried fetching manually via promise and it works but when I put everything into an array, it won't let me turn it into JSON.

```
      componentDidMount(){
        let allArticles = [];  


        for (let i=10; i>1; i--){
          allArticles.push(fetch(BASE_URL + '&page=' + i));
        }
        Promise.all(allArticles)
        .then(responses => {
          console.log(responses);
          const processedResponses = [];
          responses.map(response => {
            processedResponses.push(response);
          })
          //console.log(processedResponses);
        })

        //this works 
        // Promise.all([
        //   fetch(BASE_URL + '&page=10'),
        //   fetch(BASE_URL + '&page=9')
        // ])
        // .then(([response1, response2]) => Promise.all([response1.json(), response2.json()]))
        // .then(([data1, data2]) => this.setState({
        //   loading: false,
        //   dataSource: data1.articles.reverse()
        // }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it for every item

```
for (let i=10; i>1; i--){
  allArticles.push(fetch(BASE_URL + '&page=' + i).then(res => res.json()));
}

Promise.all(allArticles)
  .then(articles => { /* Array of parsed responses here */})
```

Otherwise you'd need to use `Promise.all` once again

```
for (let i=10; i>1; i--){
  allArticles.push(fetch(BASE_URL + '&page=' + i));
}

Promise.all(allArticles)
  .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json())))
  .then(articles => { /* Array of parsed responses here */})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that works! I also tried with .then(([response]) => Promise.all([response.json()])) as well and it works. Now the problem lies in storing it in a this.setState variable which returns a "Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object". Does Promise not accept this.setState?

Comment: @LeslieYJ `.then(([response]) => Promise.all([response.json()])) ` this only works for a single request. If you have only one request you don't need to use `Promise.all`. As of the error it's hard to say w/o [mcve]. Could you create one?

Comment: It's alright, I found it, a blunder of my part as I forgot that it was an array of articles WITHIN an array of pages, I was accessing the articles directly before accessing the array. Thanks man, you've been a great help! Cheers, and god bless you!

Comment: @LeslieYJ Glad I could help! :)